# Selenium Webdriver - Issue while opening the specified url using driver.get()

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

The Url "http://**localhost**:8080/Login.aspx" is getting opened as "http://**www.localhost.com**:8080/Login.aspx" in firefox/chrome, the error page displays "`The connection was reset The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading`". How to avoid the www.**.com issue?

I tried searching for a solution in google, but coudln't get out of this issue.

Code Sample:

```
 `BeforeClass
public void Setup(){

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://localhost:8080/Login.aspx");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}`
```

Comment: Can you access `http://www.localhost:8080/Login.aspx` directly in browser?

Comment: i can access http://localhost:8080/Login.aspx directly in browser. But while opening through selenium it is opening as `http://www.localhost.com:8080/Login.aspx`

Answer (score -1):

try the same thing in IDE with the open command and check if it works...if it does just export the code and use it.

Hope it works.

Comment: This answer is pretty much everywhere in google, and also i got rid of the issue when i executed the code on the other day without any change in it. But my concern is why that problem ever exists? What is the best way to solve other than using the IDE.